# Safe to ignore Carthage.resolved?

Tags: ios, carthage

When using Carthage I get the auto generated Carthage file in the current folder. Is it safe to git ignore it or what are its uses?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, it would not be advisable. Quoting from [Carthage's README.md on Github](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/README.md):

> Along the way, Carthage will have created some build artifacts. The most important of these is the Cartfile.resolved file, which lists the versions that were actually built for each framework. Make sure to commit your Cartfile.resolved, because anyone else using the project will need that file to build the same framework versions.
>
> After you’ve finished the above steps and pushed your changes, other users of the project only need to fetch the repository and run carthage bootstrap to get started with the frameworks you’ve added.